# Excel VBA .Formula - syntax error adding absolute reference to cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a syntax error in this VBA code:

```
students.Cells(studentRow, StartColumn).Formula = _
                        "=If($" & SurnameColumnStr & studentRow & " <> """", if($" & colonnaStr & studentRow & _
                        " <> """",  $" & colonnaStr & " & $" & pointRow & ", 0), """")"
```

I can't put right this piece of code: `$" & colonnaStr & " & $" & pointRow & "` (it would be like having `"$B$3"`)

I've tried several ways with no luck.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To get `"$B$3"` out of `colonnaStr` (a column reference) and `pointRow` (a row reference), you will need to use `Range.Address`.

Using this inside your `Formula` String:

```
Range(colonnaStr & pointRow).Address(True, True, xlA1)
```

Will give you `$B$3` as a result.

To learn more about is, read [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.address)

Comment: The strange thing is that I'm able to get "$B3" with just    $" & colonnaStr & StartRow & ", so I thought that getting "$B$3" required a similar approach. So do I really have to use Range.Address?

Comment: I find it a more reliable method, since I might use the `Range` object in another section of my VBA code, but to each...

Comment: students.Cells(studentRow, StartColumn).Formula = _
                                                            "=If($" & SurnameColumnStr & studentRow & " <> """", if($" & colonnaStr & studentRow & " <> """",  Range(colonnaStr & pointRow).Address(True, True, xlA1), 0), """")"        gives me run-time error 1004

Comment: You have `=If($" & SurnameColumnStr & studentRow & " <> """",` which is `"=IF($B$3 <> "", IF` , you need to specify the result `If $B$3 <> ""`

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand how to write the whole line of code. I'm stupid, I know.

Comment: @Dolphin975 can you write your entire formula string ? what is the result you are trying to get ?

Comment: I'm trying to get =IF($A3 <> "", IF($B3 <> "", $B$2, 0), "")

Comment: I solved. I haven't thought before, but an easy way is to create a string with the $s and use it in the formula! Sorry I didn't realize that before!